# How to get ssis package execution information during running process using ssisdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, ssis

I need to get package execution information from ssis db during runtime to log that information in my custom logging table. Is it possible to insert execution information during ssis package running on deployment?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to read from `SSISDB.catalog.executions` and `SSISDB.catalog.execution_component_phases` tables.

- [catalog.executions (SSISDB database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017)
- [catalog.execution_component_phases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-execution-component-phases?view=sql-server-2017)

TO move these rows to a custom logging table in real-time you may use triggers, i don't know if you can create triggers on SSISDB logging tables, but i think this is the only way to copy data in real-time.